# Php multi sort function

Tags: php, sorting

I'm trying to sort the standings table not only by score, but by weekly wins as well. In my league, The overall score (pick ratio) is the top dog, but wins are the tiebreaker. I have 3 people in 2nd, 2 of them with 1 win each, and another with 0. The standings page displays them out of order. Same thing with everyone in the 3rd place section, the one with 2 wins should be on top. (see link)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/taOkK.jpg

I see where it is sorting on my standings.php page:

```
$playerTotals = sort2d($playerTotals, 'score', 'desc');
```

and that calls a sorting function from my functions.php page:

```
//the following function was found at http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=71904
function sort2d ($array, $index, $order='asc', $natsort=FALSE, $case_sensitive=FALSE) {
if (is_array($array) && count($array) > 0) {
  foreach(array_keys($array) as $key) {
     $temp[$key]=$array[$key][$index];
  }
  if(!$natsort) {
     ($order=='asc')? asort($temp) : arsort($temp);
  } else {
     ($case_sensitive)? natsort($temp) : natcasesort($temp);
     if($order!='asc') {
        $temp=array_reverse($temp,TRUE);
     }
  }
  foreach(array_keys($temp) as $key) {
     (is_numeric($key))? $sorted[]=$array[$key] : $sorted[$key]=$array[$key];
  }
  return $sorted;
}
return $array;
}
```

So, I need it to sort by score first, and then wins. I have tried:

```
$playerTotals = sort2d($playerTotals, 'score', 'desc', 'wins', 'desc');
```

But that doesn't work and I know the function is not meant for that.

Comment: Why not just use a jquery sorter plugin so that people can sort it how they want?

Comment: What's wrong with just adding sort by wins in a callback function for usort? (As the `==` condition met for score)

Comment: @ChrisG I want it sorted this way, and this way only so the standings are correct.

Comment: @PhilipTsang example?

Comment: Are you trying to sort by score, and if they have the same score, sort by wins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all I needed to get the result I wanted:

```
array_multisort($score, SORT_DESC, $wins, SORT_DESC, $playerTotals);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your question, but I take it you want to sort by score and wins, with wins have lower priority? So if two players have the same score, sort by wins? If so, you can just do this, and it can be a general concept in any language:

```
usort($arrayOfPlayers, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a->score == $b->score) { //Check if score is equal
        if ($a->wins == $b->wins) { //If score is equal, sort by wins
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a->wins > $b->wins) ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return ($a->score > $b->score) ? 1 : -1; //Sort by score since not equal
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

You didn't really specify the format of your sorting, so I take it it's just an `array` of `player` objects with `wins` and `score` as properties. Please let me know if I misunderstood or if this is not the case.

Comment: Yes, it's an array of names, wins, and score. I'm not real sure how to implement your answer though.

Comment: This sorts the array into the desired order you want, `usort` is a sorting function that takes an `array_to_be_sorted` as the first parameter, and a callback function `function_to_sort_by` as the second optional parameter. You call this on the `array` of players you have.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, but would I replace the `function sort2d` with yours? I also tried `usort($playerTotals, function($a, $b) {` but I guess I'm not sure where the `$a` and `$b` is pulling from.

Comment: `$a` and `$b` are just placeholder variables, they are used for some arbitrary `a` and `b` objects in the `array`. You only need to replace the name of the actual `$array` variable, i.e. the first parameter with your array. Yes you would replace it

Comment: I can't get it to work, no matter where I put it I keep getting `unexpected T_VARIABLE` errors. Thanks though, I'll see if I can work with this.